# Laravel Schedules not working on windows

Tags: php, laravel, php-7, laravel-5.5

I can't run Schedules , daily or hourly ,...

and this code does not work

```
$schedule->call(function () {
    \DB::table('test')->delete(); // or anything else
})->everyFiveMinutes(); // tested : ->hourly() | ->daily()
```

`php artisan schedule:run`

=> No scheduled commands are ready to run.

-

*But It is working:* `$schedule->command('queue:work')`

Answer (score 1):

The information:

> No scheduled commands are ready to run

is valid. You won't see this message once every 5 minutes and in other cases you'll see this message. So you should set up cron that will run

```
php artisan schedule:run
```

every minute and you should wait for example 10 minutes to see if what was going to happen really happened. Probably the easiest way is to creating just dummy file with date of command run to make sure it's fired for example:

```
$schedule->call(function () {
    file_put_contents('schedule_report.txt', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'), FILE_APPEND);
})->everyFiveMinutes();
```